# Handle events. One by one. Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, synchronous

I have got this event listener:

```
manager.on('newOffer', (offer) => {
console.log(`We have a new offer :#${offer.id}`.bgGreen);
getInventory( function(){
processTradeOffer(offer);});});
```

My problem born when many 'newOffers' appear. They cannot been process correctly because the program is firing 'newOffers' withouting process first.

What I need(In my opinion): When an 'newOffer' appear, turn off the event listener, complete functions and then turn on again. Is that possibly?

Comment: Turning off the listener means that any events that are emitted in the mean time will get lost, is that what you want?

Comment: `processTradeOffer` is (most likely) being executed asynchronous which leads to it being called in another process while the next offer is already being loaded

Comment: @robertklep No, definitely not. But it wont happen because Iam using cookies to prevent that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sound like you need a queue with a concurrency of 1, something that [`async.queue()`](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#queue) can provide:

```
const handler = (offer, done) => {
  console.log(`We have a new offer :#${offer.id}`.bgGreen);
  getInventory(() => {
    processTradeOffer(offer); // NB: if this is async, pass a callback that calls `done`
    done();
  });
};

const queue = require('async').queue(handler, 1);

...

// Add a new offer to the queue:
let offer = new Offer(); // or however you create `offer` objects
queue.push(offer);
```

(however, this *could* become a bottleneck if you can't handle offers fast enough, in which case you may need to rethink how offers get handled)

Comment: Thank you! After a few minutes working on this. I think I got it thanks to you.